# How to know a file really exists in flutter-web

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to create and write a file in local storage using flutter-web. I don't know my code is right or not(there is no error message), and how I can find my `file.txt` from the local storage. Are there any good examples or libraries for this?

```
import 'dart:html';

class Foo {

  Future<void> writeFile(Uint8List data) async {

    FileSystem fileSystem = await window.requestFileSystem(data.length, persistent: false);
    await fileSystem.root.createFile("file.txt").then(
      (entry) async {

        if (entry.isFile) {
          (entry as FileEntry).createWriter().then(
            (writer) {
              writer.addEventListener('writeend', (event) {
                fileSystem.root.getFile("file.txt").then(
                  (value) {
                    (value as FileEntry).file().then((file) => print("writeend: ${file.name}: ${file.size} : ${file.relativePath}"));
                  }
                );
              });

              writer.addEventListener('writestart', (event) => print("writestart"));
              writer.addEventListener('progress', (event) => print("progress"));
              writer.write(new Blob(temp));
            }
          );
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```